# How to update a column in PostgreSQL with a string (converted from dictionary)?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a string obj(obj) which i got from converting from a dictionary:

```
obj = '{"a":1, "b":[{"c":2, "d":3}, {"e":5,"f":6}]}'
```

I want to update a column in the database with that string.  I tried:

```
Cursor.execute("update table emp set column1 = obj")
```

but I am getting an error:

> Psycopg2 programming error.

Comment: Please clarify your question with a specific example of what you are trying to do, and what the intended result should be.

Comment: I did edit my question. please have a look.

Comment: `obj` looks like a `dict` to me, not a string. Do you mean `obj = '{"a":1, "b":[{"c":2, "d":3}, {"e":5,"f":6}]}'`?

Comment: yeah obj is string type. i checked with type(obj).

Comment: ok. think obj is as dict. could u please tell me how to update this dict object
with my column in DB?
If i get this solution also it ll b very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `execute()` call is equivalent to typing `update table emp set column1 = obj` at the PostgreSQL console (`psql`).  That is, you're telling PostgreSQL: for each row of the `emp` table, overwrite the column named `column1` with the contents of the column named `obj`.

That's probably not what you meant to do.  In fact, your `emp` table probably doesn't even have a column named `obj`, which is why you get an error.

What you want to do is issue a [parameterized query](/q/1466741/1157100):

```
Cursor.execute("update table emp set column1 = %(obj)s",
               {'obj': obj})
```

Warning: this overwrites `column1` for every row in the table.  Make sure your `UPDATE` also includes a `WHERE` clause, if that is your intention. Something like this:

```
Cursor.execute("update table emp set column1 = %(obj)s where id = %(obj_id)s",
               {'obj': obj, 'obj_id': n})
```

Comment: Right now i need the Where clause because i want to set 
each record in DB. But I don't have the ID as it is system generated.
Could u please help me to get out of this prob.

Comment: Here Id is the primary key. so I need the update against that particular ID.

Comment: I tried with the same query giving ID in place of 'n'.
So i got the error:  Error  can't adapt type 'builtin_function_or_method